# @Input binding for function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created following custom button component. On click of this button I want to reset the form. But when I perform click action I get an error:

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined"

(as reset is a funtion).

Please help me understand where I getting wrong.

Following is my code custom component code

```
@Input() clearFormData: any;

<button *ngIf="cancelRequired" type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" 
        (click)="clearFormData()" style="margin-left:0.3em">Cancel</button>
```

I am using above component like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-model-driven',
  template: '<form-actions [clearFormData] ="clearForm"></form-actions>',
  styleUrls: ['./model-driven.component.css']
})
export class ModelDrivenComponent implements OnInit {
  clearForm() {
    this.form.reset();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare output in your custom component and handle it in the other one like this:

Custom component html file:

```
<button *ngIf="cancelRequired" type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" 
    (click)="clearFormData()" style="margin-left:0.3em">Cancel</button>
```

Custom component typescript file:

```
@Output() onReset:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

clearFormData(){
   this.onReset.emit('');
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from 
'@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-model-driven',
  template: '<form-actions (onReset) ="clearForm($event)"></form-actions>',
  styleUrls: ['./model-driven.component.css']
})
export class ModelDrivenComponent implements OnInit {
   clearForm() {
      this.form.reset();
   }
}
```

where the $event here is the value we passed it in emit function which is not useful in your case.

Can I have more than one @output in my custom component?
can I do like this if my custom component have more than one button?

```
@Output() onBack: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  backPage() {
    this.onBack.emit('');
  }

 <form-actions [cancelRequired]="true"
  (onReset)="clearForm()" (onBack)="backPageCalled()"></form-actions>
```

Comment: If I have more than one button let's say "edit" and I want to use that in my formaction component can I do that? <form-actions (onReset)="clearForm($event)" (onEdit)="editForm($event)"> like this?

Comment: Yeah you can output infinite numbers of events emitters (but of course it is like the parameters for functions, you should not output more than 3,4 events i guess).

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the functions context to the parent's component class, for example:

```
constructor(){
  this.clearForm = this.clearForm.bind(this);
}
```

now you can pass `clearForm` the function somewhere else and it's execution context will remain in the class you passed it from.

However, for this kind of operation I would suggest rather using an `@Output` from the child component. For example

```
(clearFormData)="this.form.reset()"
```

then in the component's clear button

```
(click)="this.clearFormData.emit()"
```